# Kivy 'UrlRequest' can't get json

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to get json data using kivy `UrlRequest` module from my flask api but no response(not only `on_success`...).

It worked well when I use `curl` command on my terminal(IP is dummy).

> curl http://123.12.123.xxx:1234/name/foo.json

please how to fix this?

-client.py-

```
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest

def success(req, result):
    print('success')

def fail(req, result):
    print('fail')

def error(req, result):
    print('error')

def progress(req, result, chunk):
    print('loading')

req = UrlRequest('http://123.12.123.xxx:1234/name/foo.json', on_success=success, on_failure=fail, on_error=error, on_progress=progress)
#>>
#<UrlRequest(Thread-1, started daemon 12792)>
#Press any key to continue . . .

# If using 'curl' command then success.
#{
#  "ResultSet": {
#    "Result": {
#      "Greeting": "Hello foo from flask!"
#    }
#  }
#}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `req.wait()` i.e. wait for the request to finish (until [resp_status](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.network.urlrequest.html#kivy.network.urlrequest.UrlRequest.resp_status) is not None).

## Snippets

```
req = UrlRequest('http://123.12.123.xxx:1234/name/foo.json', on_success=success, on_failure=fail, on_error=error, on_progress=progress)
req.wait()
```

Comment: Thnak you so much.